# Have Microsoft Excel of 2 languages under 1 Windows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, language

I use Microsoft Excel. 
Sometimes I need to use it in Chinese
and sometimes I need to use it in English. 
My Windows is in English.

Is it possible to configure Excel to support both languages,
or to install two copies of Excel under the same Windows
(so I can switch between them)? 
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the Chinese [Language Pack for Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Language-Accessory-Pack-for-Office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f). Then set the language setting in Excel 2016:
Click **File** > **Options** > **Language**, add Chinese under **Choose Editing Languages**. You can also **Choose Display Language** for Excel.